Why even I send GET request, the /api returns "Request body is empty" error in Symfony API Platform fusion auth based authentication
I'm new in Symfony and php. I want to authenticate users based fusion auth.
This is the action list:
Users requests for /login endpoint with their username and password.
The API sends request to /api/user to authenticate user login operation
Then the fusion provides an api auth token
Users can send to /api endpoint with this token
If this token is valid, the API is going to response for resource
Configuration file:
security:
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            custom_authenticators:
                - App\Security\TokenAuthenticator
    access_control:
        - { path: ^//login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/$, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/docs, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }

I'm getting request from this controller:
<?php

// src/Controller/SecurityController.php

namespace App\Controller\Security;

use App\Security\TokenAuthenticator;
use PHPUnit\Exception;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\Exception\ClientExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\Exception\RedirectionExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\Exception\ServerExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\Exception\TransportExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    private ?string $fusionAuthBaseUrl = null;
    private ?string $authorization = null;
    private ?string $applicationId = null;

    private ?array $headers = null;
    private ?HttpClientInterface $httpClient = null;

    public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $httpClient)
    {
        $this->httpClient = $httpClient;
        $this->fusionAuthBaseUrl = "https://example";
        $this->authorization = "authtokenprovidedfromFusionAuth";
        $this->applicationId = "applicationId";
        $this->headers = [
            'Authorization' =>$this->authorization,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ];
    }

    #[Route('/login', name: 'user-login', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function login(Request $request, TokenAuthenticator $authenticator): JsonResponse
    {
      
        $content = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $email = $content['email'] ?? null;
        $password = $content['password'] ?? null;

        try {

            // Call Fusion Auth Token endpoint to authenticate user
            $response = $this->httpClient->request('POST', $this->fusionAuthBaseUrl . '/api/login', [
                'headers' => $this->headers,
                'json' => [
                    'loginId' => $email,
                    'password' => $password,
                    'applicationId' => $this->applicationId
                ],
            ]);
            $data = $response->getContent();
            return new JsonResponse($data);

        } catch (ClientExceptionInterface $e) {
            return new JsonResponse(
                [
                    'error' => 'Client error',
                    'details' =>  $e->getMessage()
                ], 401);
        } catch (ServerExceptionInterface $e) {
            return new JsonResponse(
                [
                    'error' => 'Server error',
                    'details'=> $e->getMessage()
                ], 500);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return new JsonResponse(
                [
                    'error' => 'An unexpected error occurred',
                    'details' =>$e->getMessage()
                ], 500);
        } catch (RedirectionExceptionInterface $e) {
            return new JsonResponse(
                [
                    'error'=>'Redirection exception',
                    'details'=>$e->getMessage()
                ], 500);
        } catch (TransportExceptionInterface $e) {
            return new JsonResponse(
                [
                    'error'=>'Transport exception',
                    'details'=>$e->getMessage()
                ], 500);
        }
    }
}

User entity to store user id in database
<?php

namespace App\Entity\User;

use App\Repository\User\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'users')]
class User implements UserInterface//, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::GUID, unique: true, nullable: false)]
    //Fusionauth id
    private ?string $uuid = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    private ?string $token = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::STRING, length: 255)]
    private ?string $email = null;


    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::STRING, length: 255)]
    private ?string $roles = null;

    public function getUuid(): ?string
    {
        return $this->uuid;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        return [$this->roles];
    }

    public function setRoles(?string $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSalt(): void
    {
        
    }

    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    public function setToken (?string $token): static
    {
        $this->token = $token;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getToken(): ?string
    {
        return $this->token;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        
    }

    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->token;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return null;
    }
}

This is the user provider:
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User\User;
use App\Repository\App\UserRepository;
use PharIo\Version\Exception;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;

class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface//, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    private ?UserRepository $userRepository = null;

    public function __construct(?UserRepository $userRepository) {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername(?string $username): UserInterface
    {
        $user = $this->userRepository->findOneByUsername($username);
        if (!$user) {
            throw new \Exception(sprintf('User with username "%s" not found.', $username));
        }
        return $user;
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user): UserInterface
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Invalid user class "%s".', get_class($user)));
        }

        $refreshedUser = $this->userRepository->find($user->getUuid());

        if (!$refreshedUser) {
            throw new \Exception('User not found.');
        }

        return $refreshedUser;
    }

    public function supportsClass($class): bool
    {
        return User::class === $class;
    }

    public function loadUserByIdentifier(string $identifier): UserInterface
    {
        $user = $this->userRepository->findOneByIdentifier($identifier);

        if (!$user)
        {
           throw new \Exception(sprintf('User with identifier "%s" not found.', $identifier));
        }

        return $user;
    }
}

I'm trying to authenticate user with this authenticator:
<?php

// src/Security/TokenAuthenticator.php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\CustomCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;

class TokenAuthenticator extends AbstractAuthenticator
{
    private ?UserProvider $userProvider = null;

    public function __construct(UserProvider $userProvider)
    {
        $this->userProvider = $userProvider;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request): ?bool
    {
        return $request->headers->has('Authorization') && str_starts_with($request->headers->get('Authorization'), 'Bearer ');
    }
    public function getCredentials(Request $request): array
    {
        $token = substr($request->headers->get('Authorization'), 7); // Remove 'Bearer ' prefix
        return ['token' => $token];
    }

    public function getUser($credentials): ?UserInterface
    {
        $token = $credentials['token'];
        $user = $this->userProvider->loadUserByIdentifier($token);
        if (!$user)
        {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Invalid token');
        }
        return $user;
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);
        $user = $this->getUser($credentials);

        if (!$user) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Invalid token.');
        }

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($user->getUserIdentifier())
            new CustomCredentials(function (?array $credentials){
                return true;
            }, []
            ));
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {

        return null;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): ?Response
    {
        // Doğrulama başarısız olduğunda yapılacak işlemler
        return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'Authentication failed error',
            'exception' => $exception->getMessage(),
            'request-user' => $request->getUser(),
            'request' => $request->toArray(),
            'request-host' =>  $request->getHost(),
            'trace' => $exception->getTrace()
        ], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}

When I try to /login with my credentials, I'm getting a token from fusion. Now I need to get this token to access to the /api endpoint but when I try to send GET request with Authorization Bearer token, the API responses like that:
{
    "@id": "/api/errors/400",
    "@type": "hydra:Error",
    "title": "An error occurred",
    "detail": "Request body is empty.",
    "status": 400,
    "type": "/errors/400",
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\Onur\\Desktop\\yakalamac\\vendor\\symfony\\http-kernel\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 197,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\Onur\\Desktop\\yakalamac\\vendor\\symfony\\runtime\\Runner\\Symfony\\HttpKernelRunner.php",
            "line": 35,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\Onur\\Desktop\\yakalamac\\vendor\\autoload_runtime.php",
            "line": 29,
            "function": "run",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Runtime\\Runner\\Symfony\\HttpKernelRunner",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\Onur\\Desktop\\yakalamac\\public\\index.php",
            "line": 5,
            "function": "require_once"
        }
    ],
    "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
    "hydra:description": "Request body is empty."
}

But this is a normal GET request, so it's no need to have a body. Also I don't know how can I check this token does valid. Can you give me some idea about this please.
